# xcode NSDictionary error multiarray

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdictionary

I'm new in xcode and I need help.

I have this json:

```
{
    "noticias": [
        {
             "titulo":"teste"
        }
        {
             "titulo":"teste 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

How i got the result ? I tried

```
NSDictionary *not = [noticias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

But i got an error because I have the key "noticias"

---

**Update:** This is attempted code, on the basis of the answers received thus far. I have this:

```
- (void)fetchNoticias
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.site.com/json"]];

        NSError* error;

        noticias = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                   error:&error];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    });
}
```

Then

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self fetchNoticias];
}
```

and the final where I have the problem

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NoticiasCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSArray *noticia = [noticias objectForKey:@"noticias"];
    NSDictionary *not = [noticias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *firstTitle = [not objectForKey:@"titulo"];

    cell.textLabel.text = firstTitle;
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = subtitulo;

    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    return cell;
}
```

problem in line:

```
NSArray *noticia = [noticias objectForKey:@"noticias"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. Your JSON is not well formed, missing a comma. It should be:

   ```
   {
       "noticias": [
                    {
                    "titulo":"teste"
                    },
                    {
                    "titulo":"teste 2"
                    }
                    ]
   }
   ```

   If you don't add that missing comma, you'll get an error from your parser. For example, `NSJSONSerialization` will report:

   > Badly formed array around character 109
2. To read the contents, you would load a `NSData` with the contents of the JSON and then parse it, for example:

   ```
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename]; // or [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
   NSError *error = nil;
   NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

   if (error)
       NSLog(@"%@", error);
   else
   {
       NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"noticias"];
       NSDictionary *item = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       NSString *title = [item objectForKey:@"titulo"];

       NSLog(@"%@", firstTitle);
   }
   ```

   or, using the new, simpler syntax:

   ```
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename]; // or [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
   NSError *error = nil;
   NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

   if (error)
       NSLog(@"%@", error);
   else
   {
       NSArray *array = dictionary[@"noticias"];
       NSDictionary *item = array[indexPath.row];
       NSString *title = item[@"titulo"];

       NSLog(@"%@", title);
   }
   ```

---

First, define a property for your `noticias` in the `@interface` for your class:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *noticias;
```

Then read your `noticias`:

```
- (void)fetchNoticias
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.site.com/json"]];

        NSError* error = nil;

        NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                options:kNilOptions
                                                                  error:&error];

        if (error) 
        {
            NSLog(@"%s: error=%@", __FUNCTION__, error);
            return;
        }

        self.noticias = [results objectForKey:@"noticias"];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    });
}
```

Then

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self fetchNoticias];
}
```

and, finally, `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NoticiasCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *noticia = [self.noticias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *firstTitle = [noticia objectForKey:@"titulo"];

    cell.textLabel.text = firstTitle;
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = subtitulo;

    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @user1535906 I've updated my answer on the basis of your expanded code sample.

Answer (score 1):

suppose your jsonData is "response"

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* ResponseDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
NSArray* noticias = [ResponseDic objectForKey:@"noticias"];
NSDictionary* not = [noticias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

hope this help you.

Comment: where do you get your jsonData?

Comment: now it`s ok...but i duplicated the code that already exist in fetchNoticias

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
      NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"noticias"];
      for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
      {
       NSDictionary *item = [array objectAtIndex:i];
      NSString *title = [item objectForKey:@"titulo"];
       NSLog(@"%@",title);
      }
```

hope it help you.